# how can I color specific points based on two data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two datasets melted. I want to plot

```
df <-structure(list(test = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "D", class = "factor"), 
    N = 1:15, value = c(0.193333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
    0.226666666666667, 0.233333333333333, 0.246666666666667, 
    0.113333333333333, 0.14, 0.126666666666667, 0.233333333333333, 
    0.206666666666667, 0.14, 0.26, 0.213333333333333, 0.206666666666667, 
    0.22)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

and my df2 is

```
df2 <- structure(list(test = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), N = 1:15, value = c(0.00734658620417139, 
0.0310075916430482, 0.000899636750923194, 0.000567925967793537, 
0.000217454812833306, 0.290391297453855, 0.105715835833684, 0.180098464605175, 
0.000567925967793537, 0.00330103411768823, 0.105715835833684, 
7.89376056511415e-05, 0.00216893397611406, 0.00330103411768823, 
0.00140621607072411)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

I plot the df like this

```
qplot(data = df, x = value,y = N,color=N)+geom_point()
```

I want to plot those that their value in df is lower than 0.13 and also their corresponding value in df2 is lower than 0.5 in red.

for example in this case, look at the N in both data ( number 6) the df value is 0.11 and the value in df2 is 2.903913e-01 which is smaller than 0.5 so , I want it to be colored in red .

I don't mind if you use something other than **qplot**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option. Essentially you have to make a categorical variable that you can later use in ggplot to specify the color of the points.

```
# join data frames to facilitate comparison of values:
dfComb <- full_join(df, df2, by = c("N"))

dfComb %>% 
  mutate(
    colorVar = case_when( # categorize data points based on your logic (if_else would also be nice)
      value.x < .13 & value.y < .5 ~ "red",
      TRUE ~ "not red"
    )
  ) %>% # pipe dataset into ggplot...
  ggplot() +
  geom_point( # the aesthetics here match your qplot
    aes(value.x, N, color = colorVar)
    ) +
  scale_color_manual( # set colors manually to get red
    values = c("blue", "red")
  )
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: If `dplyr` is not a desired package, base-R is (in this case) straight-forward: `merge(df, df2, by="N", all=TRUE)`.